# jQuery Serialize?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery

### ORIGINAL POST:

I have the following script which serializes nicely.

jQuery/Ajax generated HTML

```
<ul class="my_list">
    <li class="list_item_1"><a href="link1.html">link1</a></li>
    <li class="list_item_2"><a href="link2.html">link2</a></li>
    <li class="list_item_3"><a href="link3.html">link3</a></li>
    <li class="list_item_4"><a href="link4.html">link4</a></li>
    <li class="list_item_5"><a href="link5.html">link5</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".my_list").sortable(
    {update:function(){
         alert($(this).sortable("serialize"));
    }
});
```

Is it possible to do a similar thing with the anchor tags url and text?

i.e. something along the lines of:

```
$(".my_list").sortable(
    {update:function(){
         alert($(this).sortable("serialize"));
         alert($("detect_anchor_tag_in_li").serialize_url)); // anchorurl_1=link1.html&anchorurl_2=link2.html and so on
         alert($("detect_anchor_tag_in_li").serialize_text)); // anchortext_1=link1&anchor_2=link2 and so on
    }
});
```

### UPDATED POST 1:

The following return "undefined" for elt.text.

```
    <script>
        $( document ).ready( function() { 
            $(".my_list").sortable(
                {axis:"y"},
                {update:function(){ 
                    alert($(this).sortable("serialize",{key:'widget_id'}));

                    $.map($(".my_list a"), function(elt, index) { 
                        alert("url=" + elt.href + " txt=" + elt.text); 
                    }); 
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

### UPDATED POST 2:

The following works, but is it the best way to go about doing this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>sortable basic</title>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $( document ).ready( function() { 
                var urls = ""; 
                var texts = ""; 

                $("#mylist").sortable(
                    {axis: "y"},
                    {update:function(){ 
                        $.map($("#mylist a"), function(elt) { 
                            urls += "url=" + elt.href + "&";
                            texts += "text=" + $(elt).html() + "&"; 
                        }); 

                        alert($(this).sortable("serialize",{key:'item'}));
                        alert(urls.substr(0,urls.length - 1));
                        alert(texts.substr(0,texts.length - 1));
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul id="mylist">
            <li id="item_4"><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></li>
            <li id="item_9"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a></li>
            <li id="item_2"><a href="http://www.bing.com">bing</a></li>
            <li id="item_5"><a href="http://www.youtube.com">youtube</a></li>
            <li id="item_8"><a href="http://www.ebay.com">ebay</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi is the problem on serialization or on anchor detection ?

Comment: Both, but I guess the best starting point would be to detect the anchor tags within that particular ul tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `map` function to change an array of results to another. Then join it with the '&' and voila!

```
$.map(
    $(".my_list a")
    , function(elt, index) {
        return "anchorurl_" + index + "=" + elt.href
    }).join("&");

 $.map(
    $(".my_list a")
    , function(elt, index) {
        return "anchortext_" + index + "=" + elt.text
    }).join("&");
```

It's working, but you may want to keep the $(".my_list a") array to reuse it in next calls (even though it shouldn't be too expensive to get the list)

---

edit to add:
you can in fact do lots of interesting things with the map function.
Return an array of data objects built from your links data?

```
$.map(
        $(".my_list a")
        , function(elt, index) {
            return {anchor: elt.href, text: elt.text };
        });
```

or an array of arrays

```
$.map(
        $(".my_list a")
        , function(elt, index) {
            return [[elt.href, elt.text]];
        });
```

So, basically, i think map is highly recommended in your case :)

---

edit for IE8 specific problem

I just tried this, and it works on firefox 3.6

```
<ul id="listing">
    <li class="list_item_1"><a href="link1.html">link1</a></li>
    <li class="list_item_2"><a href="link2.html">link2</a></li>
    <li class="list_item_3"><a href="link3.html">link3</a></li>
    <li class="list_item_4"><a href="link4.html">link4</a></li>
    <li class="list_item_5"><a href="link5.html">link5</a></li>
</ul>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#listing").sortable(
            { update: function(event, ui) {
                $.map($("#listing a"), function(elt, index) {
                                   alert("url=" + elt.href + " txt=" + elt.text);
                               });
            }});
       });
   </script>
```

---

you can try with `$(this).text()` or `$(elt).html()` (the first one should be better), i had it work on both browsers. I'm not fluent with the development tools for IE8 so i'd recommend you find documentation to read about determining the properties of an object.
[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_a.asp) doesnt give a text attribute for the a tag, i should have checked that first...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#listing").sortable(
            { update: function(event, ui) {
                $.map($("#listing a"), function(elt, index) {
                    alert("url=" + elt.href + " txt=" + $(elt).text());
                });
            }});
       });
   </script>
```

---

The last edit, just to make things "perfect"
to reuse the method, for another list, change the map selection from 
`$.map($("#listing a")...` to `$.map($("a", event.target)...`. This way, you doin't have to worry about the id being repeated in the function body.

Comment: I'll try this out tomorrow first thing.

Comment: I think I am doing this wrong, because I cant get it to return the text of the anchor tag.  I have updated the original post to show you what I currently have.

Comment: you're using an id hash instead of a class selector, is that on purpose? If you're using firebug on firefox, use the console to make sure your selector is correct. Alternatively, set up a breakpoint in the javascript using a "debugger" statement and watch what elt is

Comment: i have internet explorer 8. where do i enter the debugger statement?  Fixed the id hash, that was a typo.

Comment: I have just tried it in Firefox 4.0, Chromium 9.0, Opera 11 and it worked for all of them.  However, the same page will not work on internet explorer 8.  Unfortunately, I need it to work on internet explorer 8 more than the rest of the browsers.  elt.txt seems to give undefined on ie8.

Comment: I have added a new update to the original question.  Is that the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you could do this with the sortable plugin but why not do it yourself, something like this:

```
var serialized = "";

$('.my_list li a').each(function(index)
{
    serialized+= "anchorurl_" + index + "=" + $(this).attr("href")
});
```

Comment: Is this method better than the method posted by samy?  If yes, please let me know why. Thanks.

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong, please see my updated question above.  Thanks.

Comment: So how do I use this method to get the text of the anchor tag?